# How to .gitignore subdirectories by their contents?

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm working on a project where one of the functionalities is generation of git repositories with a particular structure.

Because of this, I often end up with a lot of untracked "submodules" in my project repository, that generate unnecessary noise. Even `git clean -dfx` refuses to clean them up:

```
> git clean -dfx
Skipping repository generated/
```

I tried to be clever, and put the following rule in my `.gitignore`, but to no avail:

```
*/.git/../*
```

Is there a way to ignore subdirectories that *contain* files adhering to a certain pattern?

Comment: To get `git clean` to remove outdated nested repos double the `f` option, see its docs.  Since you're creating these nested repos, why not name them something identifiable?

Comment: @jthill it might be a good idea, it's just a bit unwieldy. I sometimes don't have any way of customizing the generated directory's name.

Comment: Then you've got a workflow far enough off the beaten path it'll need a little light scripting.